# Проблемы с реализацией RecyclerViewAdapter. Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

В моей активности есть RecyclerView.  Код адаптера для него:

```
public class StoryListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StoryListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Story> storyList;
    private Context context;

    StoryListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Story> storyList){
        this.storyList = storyList;
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public StoryListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StoryListAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        final Story story = storyList.get(i);
        viewHolder.tv.setText(story.getTitle());
        viewHolder.cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,StoryViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("number", story.getNumber());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return storyList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView tv;
        final CardView cv;
        ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            cv = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cv_item);
            tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_item);
        }
    }
}
```

Инициализация адаптера и ArrayList'a для него происходят в отдельном потоке:

```
private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Начало загрузки
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // pb - ProgressBar
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        stories = Parser.getStoriesByTag(tag); // stories - ArrayList который хранит в себе объекты класса Story
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        adapter = new StoryListAdapter(StoryListActivity.this,stories); // Установка адаптера
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Но после окончания потока, на экране пользователя не появляется содержания RecyclerView, несмотря на то что stories(ArrayList использующийся в адаптере) заполнен объектами. И насколько я понимаю проблема в коде адаптера (но это не точно)
Подскажите что я делаю не так и как это исправить?

Comment: `rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));` - Попробуй над реализацией адаптера задать ресайклу лейаут.

Comment: @McDaggen, дейсвительно. Мне это помогло, спасибо

Comment: Вывел в ответ, пожалуйста отметь галочкой, чтобы те, кто будет искать вопрос по теме воспользовались рабочим ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй перед реализацией адаптера задать ресайклу лейаут.

```
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```